# Should rbenv be installed system-wide, or at a user level?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, vagrant, rbenv

I'm building a vagrant setup, and part of that is installing rbenv. I'm using librarian-chef to manage all my chef cookbooks, and it installs rbenv and ruby-build.

However, when I tried to ssh into my Vagrant VM and type `ruby -v` I got the standard system-installed `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]`. Thinking that maybe rbenv was not installed, I tried running `rbenv versions`, but rbenv was in fact installed:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /opt/rbenv/version)
```

So then I tried `rbenv install [version]`:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p327
[...]

BUILD FAILED
[...]

test -z "/opt/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/opt/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/include"
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327': Permission denied
```

That failed with `Permission denied`. I tried installing again with `sudo`:

```
sudo rbenv install 1.9.3-p327
```

And that worked. Then I tried running `rbenv versions` again:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /opt/rbenv/version)
```

But it still says only `system` ruby is installed. However, if I run it with `sudo`:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo rbenv versions
* system (set by /home/vagrant/.rbenv/version)
  1.9.3-p327
```

`rbenv versions` now shows `1.9.3` was installed.

So there seems to be a disconnect, in that that rbenv and my ruby version are now installed on a system level and not on the user level.

I am using the [rbenv-cookbook](https://github.com/RiotGames/rbenv-cookbook). I would like to have rbenv set up with chef, because that saves me from setting it up manually, post-install.

The other issue I'm having is that it seem like everything that is ruby-controlled, such as `gem`, is also suffering the same disconnect.

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

About two years ago, a [discussion happened in github](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/38) about shared installs, which appears to answer the question.

**Synopsis**: sstephenson (rbenv author) specifically doesn't like encouraging system-wide installs because of complexities with permissions, write access, etc.  He believes adding robust support would make rbenv more complex, and simplicity is the goal.

**EDIT**

I've since come across fnichol's chef-rbenv cookbook, which, if you actually want to install a system-wide rbenv, gives a [right and proper method](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv/blob/master/recipes/system_install.rb), and you can automate it with Chef (I recommend knife solo).

It installs this to `/etc/profile.d/` so it will run for all users, [putting the proper ruby into the `PATH`](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv/blob/master/templates/default/rbenv.sh.erb).

Comment: For future people - [this method](https://gist.github.com/yuriihabrusiev/7356212) to rbenv install to `/usr/local/rbenv` works. If you're on zsh, you will need to add `. /etc/profile` to `/etc/zsh/zprofile` to include the `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` file created in that method.

Answer (score 15):

rbenv should be installed at a user level.

Unfortunately, this means that when running `gem install`, you may run into the problem you saw:

```
You don't have write permissions into the {...} directory
```

You can solve this by setting the correct permissions on the `~/.rbenv` directory.

```
sudo chown -R yourusername ~/.rbenv
```

After `chown`ing the directory, you'll be able to run `gem install` without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in rbenv's Readme is assume a local (per-user) installation in `~/.rbenv/` so i would assume that the official recommendation is to install it on a per-user basis.

Still, it's possible to install it globally. But you'll need `sudo` for all commands that need to writing rights. Installing new rubies, installing gems* and changing the global ruby  version are the ones coming to my mind here, there might be more.

(*) Needing sudo for installing new gems is the default when you install your ruby through the default system routines like apt on debian, not needing sudo for it is actually a positive side effect of using ruby version managers that work on a per-user basis

Comment: This article has instructions: http://blakewilliams.me/blog/4-system-wide-rbenv-install Also changes the group to staff and gives group permissions + sets the sticky bit, so you should be able to install and use rubies from any user.  I am not sure if this is recommended though, and unsure why or why not.